# gets(); function not waiting for input on second loop in C

Tags: c, scanf, gets

I'm writing a program that simulates purchasing cars. The program works well the first go around, but after the purchase is made and the prompt asks for a name, `gets()` does not search for input. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
int j=1;
int prices[5] = { 24000,28000,25000,20000,120000 };
int invent[5] = { 5,2,3,8,2 };
int purchased[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int main()
{
    char name[50];

    printf("Welcome to Buy-a-Car!\nPlease enter your name:\n");
    gets(name);
    printf("Welcome, %s. Here is our available inventory.\n", name);
    sale();
    return 0;
}

void sale()
{
    while (i>0, j != 0) {
        printf("1. Toyota Camry      %d  %d\n2. Honda CRV         %d  %d\n3. Honda Accord      %d  %d\n4. Hyundai Elantra   %d  %d\n5. Audi R8           %d %d", invent[0], prices[0], invent[1], prices[1], invent[2], prices[2], invent[3], prices[3], invent[4], prices[4]);
        printf("\nWhich car would you like to purchase?\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        i = i - 1;
        printf("How many would you like to purchase?\n(Note: To checkout, please press 0.)\n");
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if (j > invent[i])
            printf("I'm sorry, that number is insufficient. Please try again.\n");
        else
            invent[i] = invent[i] - j;
        purchased[i] = j;
    }
    checkout();
}
void checkout()
{
    printf("Review of transaction:\n1. Toyota Camry     %d  %d\n2. Honda CRV        %d  %d\n3. Honda Accord     %d  %d\n4. Hyundai Elantra  %d  %d\n5. Audi R8          %d %d", purchased[0], prices[0], purchased[1], prices[1], purchased[2], prices[2], purchased[3], prices[3], purchased[4], prices[4]);
    int total;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        total = total + (purchased[i] * prices[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal: %d\n\n\n", total);

    j = 1;
    int purchased[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    main();
}
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, I'd like to point out that the `gets()` function has been deprecated long time ago, because it is inherently unsafe. You should probably exchange it for `scanf()` or `gets_s()`.

Comment: Windows 10. I am using an online compiler that does not recognize _s functions. I would use scanf if not for fear of data loss (i.e. customer enters first and last name, scanf only reads first).

Comment: How is the program ever supposed to terminate?

Comment: There is no `gets` in my compiler.

Comment: I've added a for loop that terminates after five customers, but that's not the important part. The question is regarding the failure for gets(); to receive a second input. When ran, the second loop reads the name as a space.

Comment: @J.Doe, please review [MCVE] and post the actual code that you need help with.  The `checkout` function you posted calls `main()`, I don't see how it can ever terminate and the code will not compile.

Comment: `get()` is deprecated, do not use it. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Calling `main()` invokes undefined behaviour. Do not do this, solve your need to a loop differently.

Comment: @alk Calling `main` is allowed in C.

Comment: This is a duplicate of all the other fgets/scanf questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the '\n' char in buffer after use scanf, use scanf("%d%*c",&var); %*c prevents '\n' to skip line when gets is used

gets is not safe, use fgets(&str,sizeof(str),stdin);

Answer (score 0):

After running `scanf()`, the Enter (and anything before) is still in the input buffer. You can clear it like this:

```
scanf("%*[\n]%*c");
```

or

```
while( getchar() != '\n' );
```

Now `gets()` won't return an empty string. But anyway, it's *extremely* discouraged to use it. Use `fgets` or `scanf("%[^\n]")` instead.

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
// or
scanf("%[^\n]", name);
```

Besides, **don't call `main()` from anywhere in your program**. Its behavior is undefined. You can wrap the whole stuff up in another function, and use a loop. An endless recursion call will surely end up blowing up the stack.